# Simple math operations in Swift not working as they should

Tags: swift

Alright, let's imagine I have an NSDate object `date`, that is in the past, and I want to calculate the number of seconds that have passed. This is how I do it:

```
let timeInterval = -date.timeIntervalSinceNow
```

Then I want to decompose that into minutes, seconds and centi-seconds:

```
let seconds = Int(timeInterval) % 60
let minutes = Int(timeInterval - seconds) / 60
let centiSeconds = Int((timeInterval - Int(timeInterval)) * 100)
```

Except that the compiler complains about the last two lines, and I cannot figure out why.

For the `minutes` line it says `Could not find and overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments`, and for the `centiSeconds` line it says `Could not find and overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments`. What am I doing wrong? Isn't this acceptable in Swift-land?

Comment: If Swift is anything like C or Java, you cannot do `Int(timeInterval - seconds)` -- a type override on an expression. Try `Int(timeInterval) - Int(seconds)` (the type overrides may even be redundant).

Comment: @Jongware well, that worked for the second line. I'll have to think of a different expression for the third line so that I don't have to do a type override on an expression. By the way, what is the reasoning behind this prohibition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all a matter of where you apply the cast:

```
let timeInterval = -now.timeIntervalSinceNow

let seconds = Int(timeInterval) % 60
let minutes = (Int(timeInterval) - seconds) / 60
let centiSeconds = timeInterval - floor(timeInterval)) * 100
```

The underlying issue is that `now.timeIntervalSinceNow` returns an NSTimeInterval which is a floating point. As a result, the following is a compilation error:

```
let minutes = Int(timeInterval - seconds) / 60
```

However, the error Xcode reports `Could not find and overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments` is incorrect and is not the root cause here.

Comment: Well, that does work perfectly, but why does the place of the cast matter?

Comment: It is important to note that you must use floor instead of relying on the Int truncation because of negative numbers: Int(-30.9) is -30 while floor(-30.9) is -31

Comment: @Alex very good question, I am still trying to work that out!

Comment: The behaviour is most odd, this work `let minutes = Int(Int(timeInterval) - seconds) / 60` - so you can use expressions

Comment: I think it is the error reporting that is wonky. You cannot do `timeInterval - seconds` because timeInterval is a Double and seconds is an Int. They must match in types. Same goes for the last line.

Comment: Ah, it is because now.timeIntervalSinceNow is an NSNumber, which is why you need to convert it to an Int. Hence `Int(timeInterval - seconds) / 60` fails. However, the error message you are receiving `Could not find and overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments` appears to be incorrect. I think this is most likely a minor issue in the compiler's error reporting.

Comment: @drewag you are 30 seconds ahead of me ;-)

Comment: @drewag "timeInterval is a Double and seconds is an Int": I noticed that discrepancy in their types, but I thought Swift, like C and Obj-C, could add ints to doubles. IMO, swift should understand that double+int=double (and float+double=double, int+int=int, etc...), and so perform the addition accordingly. Am I wrong? Also, you're totally right about the floor *vs* Int comment. I completely forgot about the floor function.

Comment: @Alex The language developers decided to not allow implicit conversion like `double + int = double` for safety reasons. All type conversions must be done explicitly. `double + int = double` might be easy but cases like `"1" + 2 = ?` become more ambiguous.

Comment: @drewag Ohh, I see. Alright. So to perform double+int=double I actually need to write double+Double(int). Is that it?